# Selecting numeric columns in apply function without using another step in R

Tags: r

Is there anyway that I can select numeric columns in apply function without using another step? In the following code I have to use `select_if(is.numeric)` to achieve this. I would like to use the selection function in the `apply` itself. Any ideas?

```r
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)
palmerpenguins::penguins |> drop_na() |> select_if(is.numeric) |> 
  apply(2, \(x) mean(x, na.rm = T))
#>    bill_length_mm     bill_depth_mm flipper_length_mm       body_mass_g 
#>          43.99279          17.16486         200.96697        4207.05706 
#>              year 
#>        2008.04204
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr::summarize()` is probably more suitable for this task

```
library(tidyverse)

palmerpenguins::penguins %>% 
  summarize(across(where(is.numeric), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 1 × 5
  bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_length_mm body_mass_g  year
           <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
1           43.9          17.2              201.       4202. 2008.
```

Comment: I know this answer. But I wanted to use ```apply``` here.